# When a user creates a subscription and pays, in the "stripe" console nothing was charge, 0 pesos were sent

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, vercel

When the subscription is created, like this:

```
import Stripe from 'stripe';

const stripe = Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_API_KEY_SERVER);
const freePlan =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? 'price_xxxx'
    : 'price_xxxx';

export default async (req, res) => {
  const { customerId, tokenId, price } = req.body;

  try {
    const source = await stripe.customers.createSource(customerId, {
      source: tokenId,
    });

    if (!source) {
      return res.json({ ok: false, error: 'Stripe failed to attach card' });
    }

    const sub = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
      customer: customerId,
      items: [{ price }],
      trial_end:
        price === freePlan
          ? new Date(Date.now() + 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
          : undefined,
    });

    return res.json({ ok: true, subId: sub.id });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return res.json({ ok: false, error });
  }
};
```

The petition is successful, but when we see the stripe console, nothing was charge...

[image]

And the product has its price... (In this case, was used "Plan mensual").

[image]

What can we do? Thanks!

Comment: Is 'Plan mensual' a metered price? If so, then you have to include usage (https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/metered-billing) for it to be properly billed

Comment: Maybe you can send me an example :), I dont know what to do exactly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With metered prices usage is not specified as part of the call to create the Subscription. Instead, as your customer uses your product you would report that usage back to Stripe using the Usage Record API (https://stripe.com/docs/api/usage_records/create). At the end of each billing period, Stripe charge the Customer based on the reported usage. You can see a full walk-through on how to used metered billing with subscriptions here (https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/metered#report-usage).

If you actually know the quantity for the subscription item up front (when the subscription is created), then you probably want to switch to a licensed price instead of a metered price.

Comment: THank you! Yes, I just created a new one without that and works great! THank you so much for the comment!